# hibernate association with n levels

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables (ProspectMaster,ProspectContactsMaster). to maintain a relationship, I made a mapping table(ProspectContactsMap) using an embeddable entity(ProspectContactsMapID). Bellow are the all entities

```
@Entity
public class ProspectMaster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int prospectID;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Length(max = 50)
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "prospectContactsMapID.prospectMaster", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ProspectContactsMap> prospectContactsMap = new HashSet<ProspectContactsMap>(0);

    public int getProspectID() {
        return prospectID;
    }

    public void setProspectID(int prospectID) {
        this.prospectID = prospectID;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Set<ProspectContactsMap> getProspectContactsMap() {
        return prospectContactsMap;
    }

    public void setProspectContactsMap(Set<ProspectContactsMap> prospectContactsMap) {
        this.prospectContactsMap = prospectContactsMap;
    }

}

@Entity
public class ProspectContactsMaster {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int prospectContactID;

    @Length(max = 25)
    private String firstName;

    public int getProspectContactID() {
        return prospectContactID;
    }

    public void setProspectContactID(int prospectContactID) {
        this.prospectContactID = prospectContactID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}

@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "prospectContactsMapID.prospectMaster", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "prospectID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "prospectContactsMapID.prospectContactsMaster", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "prospectContactID")) })
public class ProspectContactsMap {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProspectContactsMapID prospectContactsMapID = new ProspectContactsMapID();

    private int isMainContact;

    @Transient
    public ProspectMaster getProspectMaster() {
        return this.getProspectContactsMapID().getProspectMaster();
    }

    public void setProspectMaster(ProspectMaster prospectMaster) {
        getProspectContactsMapID().setProspectMaster(prospectMaster);
    }

    @Transient
    public ProspectContactsMaster getProspectContactsMaster() {
        return this.getProspectContactsMapID().getProspectContactsMaster();
    }

    public void setProspectContactsMaster(ProspectContactsMaster prospectContactsMaster) {
        getProspectContactsMapID().setProspectContactsMaster(prospectContactsMaster);
    }

    public ProspectContactsMapID getProspectContactsMapID() {
        return prospectContactsMapID;
    }

    public void setProspectContactsMapID(ProspectContactsMapID prospectContactsMapID) {
        this.prospectContactsMapID = prospectContactsMapID;
    }

    public int getIsMainContact() {
        return isMainContact;
    }

    public void setIsMainContact(int isMainContact) {
        this.isMainContact = isMainContact;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class ProspectContactsMapID implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private ProspectMaster prospectMaster;

    @ManyToOne
    private ProspectContactsMaster prospectContactsMaster;

    public ProspectMaster getProspectMaster() {
        return prospectMaster;
    }

    public void setProspectMaster(ProspectMaster prospectMaster) {
        this.prospectMaster = prospectMaster;
    }

    public ProspectContactsMaster getProspectContactsMaster() {
        return prospectContactsMaster;
    }

    public void setProspectContactsMaster(ProspectContactsMaster prospectContactsMaster) {
        this.prospectContactsMaster = prospectContactsMaster;
    }
}
```

now my requirement is to fetch all prospect having company name starts with d or having main contacts starts with d. I have made a query, but in n level I can not provide association property. Bellow is my query

```
Disjunction disjOrCondition = Restrictions.disjunction(); 
Criteria cr = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ProspectMaster.class);
cr.createAlias("prospectContactsMap", "prospectContact");

Criterion thirdCondition = Restrictions.conjunction().add(Restrictions.eq("prospectContact.isMainContact",1))
    .add(Restrictions.like("prospectContact.prospectContactsMapID.prospectContactsMaster.firstName", searchVal.toString(),MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
disjOrCondition.add(Restrictions.like("companyName", searchVal.toString(),MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
disjOrCondition.add(thirdCondition);
```

if I run this, I get bellow exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: prospectContactsMapID.prospectContactsMaster.firstName
```

can anyone please tell me where is the problem? and can anyone tell me any example on same. I want to use hql only.

Comment: In what concerns the tables: do you have in ProspectMaster table a foreign id to ProspectContactsMap? 

My guess is that there is a problem with the "embedable" entity. In case you have foreign keys, you wont need a mapping table, you could use one-to-many without it and without this: `.add(Restrictions.like("prospectContact.prospectContactsMapID.prospectContactsMaster.firstName"`

Comment: look, my associations are working fine, cause in insert there is no problem, only there is problem to fetch data in n depth association. Even my association is working upto 2nd level not more than that

Answer (score 0):

From what I know I just can tell you 2 things:

- you can try another fetching strategy; instead of LAZY you could try EAGER
- there is a property in the configuration file: [hibernate.max_fetch_depth](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional), but i guess you are using the default. It sets the maximum depth for a single-ended asociation.